# How do I pip install from Google Code?

Tags: python, repository, pip, google-code

I'm trying to install the Gevent beta which is hosted on [Google Code here](http://code.google.com/p/gevent/downloads/list) but I can't seem to get the command right (I keep getting a **cannot detect archive format** error). What is the command to pip install gevent-1.0b4 from Google Code?

Here is the command and error:

`(venv)zak$ pip install https://code.google.com/p/gevent/gevent-1.0b4.tar.gz
Downloading/unpacking https://code.google.com/p/gevent/gevent-1.0b4.tar.gz
  HTTP error 404 while getting https://code.google.com/p/gevent/gevent-1.0b4.tar.gz
  Could not install requirement https://code.google.com/p/gevent/gevent-1.0b4.tar.gz because of error HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Could not install requirement https://code.google.com/p/gevent/gevent-1.0b4.tar.gz because of HTTP error HTTP Error 404: Not Found for URL https://code.google.com/p/gevent/gevent-1.0b4.tar.gz`

Comment: `pip install http://gevent.googlecode.com/files/gevent-1.0b4.tar.gz` works just fine for me.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gevent/gevent-1.0b4.tar.gz gives a 404. How did you construct this URL?

Comment: Copy and pasted it from Google Code.

Comment: I don't think so, that link is nowhere to be found on the download list page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is wrong, it returns a **404** (which you can verify by visiting it in your browser).

```
pip install http://gevent.googlecode.com/files/gevent-1.0b4.tar.gz
```

would work. But as it says on the project home page on Google Code, gevent now lives on [github](https://github.com/SiteSupport/gevent).

So it's

```
pip install https://github.com/downloads/SiteSupport/gevent/gevent-1.0b4.tar.gz
```

Comment: I would instead go with ``pip install git+git://github.com/SiteSupport/gevent.git@1.0b4#egg=gevent`` with this, you can easily change the ``@`` to point to any commit in the repository, not just a tagged release

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip install http://gevent.googlecode.com/files/gevent-1.0b4.tar.gz`